# After declaring and implementing the function, main still cannot find the function

Tags: c++, function, templates

When I declare, implement, and call function in main function, my compiler still reports errors that cannot be resolved by external symbols;All of my code are given following;the problem details are between '*'.

The specific error statement is:

```
1.LNK2019   无法解析的外部符号 "void __cdecl CreateBinaryTree(void)" (?CreateBinaryTree@@YAXXZ)，函数 main 中引用了该符号  DataStructure   C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Code\Visual、Studio\DataStructure\BinaryTree.obj 
2.LNK2019   无法解析的外部符号 "void __cdecl ShowBinaryTree(void)" (?ShowBinaryTree@@YAXXZ)，函数 main 中引用了该符号  DataStructure   C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Code\Visual Studio\DataStructure\BinaryTree.obj 
3.LNK2019   无法解析的外部符号 "void __cdecl InsertInOrderThreadTree(void)" (?InsertInOrderThreadTree@@YAXXZ)，函数 main 中引用了该符号    DataStructure   C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Code\Visual Studio\DataStructure\BinaryTree.obj 1   
4.LNK2019   无法解析的外部符号 "void __cdecl InOrderThreadTree(void)" (?InOrderThreadTree@@YAXXZ)，函数 main 中引用了该符号    DataStructure   C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Code\Visual Studio\DataStructure\BinaryTree.obj 
5.LNK2019   无法解析的外部符号 "void __cdecl Traversal(void)" (?Traversal@@YAXXZ)，函数 main 中引用了该符号    DataStructure   C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Code\Visual Studio\DataStructure\BinaryTree.obj 1
```

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MaxSize 100

template<class T>
struct LinkNode {
    //implement
};

template<class T>
struct ThreadNode {
    //implement
};

template<class T>
struct TreeNode {
    //implement
};

template<class T>
class MyStack {
        //implement
};

template<class T>
LinkNode<T>* root;
template<class T>
ThreadNode<T>* threadNode;

//*************************************************************************************
void CreateBinaryTree();
void ShowBinaryTree();
void InsertInOrderThreadTree();
void InOrderThreadTree();
void InsertInOrderThreadTree();
void Traversal();

int main() {
    CreateBinaryTree();
    ShowBinaryTree();
    Traversal();
    InsertInOrderThreadTree();
    InOrderThreadTree();
}
//*************************************************************************************

//选择遍历方式
template<class T>
void Traversal() {
    //implement
}

//RecursiveTraversal
template<class T>
void preOrder(LinkNode<T>* p) {
    //implement
}

template<class T>
void inOrder(LinkNode<T>* p) {
    //implement
}

template<class T>
void postOrder(LinkNode<T>* p) {
    //implement
}

//nonRecursiveTraversal
template<class T>
void nonRecursivePreOrder(LinkNode<T>* p) {
    //implement
}

template<class T>
void nonRecursiveInOrder(LinkNode<T>* p) {
    //implement
}

template<class T>
void nonRecursivePostOrder(LinkNode<T>* p) {
    //implement
}

template<class T>
void InThread(ThreadNode<T>*& p,ThreadNode<T>*& pre) {
    //implement
}

template<class T>
void InOrderThreadTree() {
    //implement
}

template<class T>
void InsertInOrderThreadTree() {
    //implement
    
}

template<class T>
void CreateBinaryTree() {
    //implement
}

template<class T>
void ShowBinaryTree() {
    //implement
}
```

I hope someone can answer my questions. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file), but it isn't clear what the non-template declarations are supposed to do here and which file is separate from others.

Comment: There is indeed no non-template definitions. You have declared non-template functions and then defined function templates.

Comment: The declaration `void CreateBinaryTree();` is a non template declaration while you have defined it as a template `template<class T> void CreateBinaryTree() {
    //implement
}`

Comment: FYI, [why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've **declared** your functions as **non-templates** but **defined/implemented** them as templates.

To solve this you can change the **definitions** of those functions to be non-templated as shown below.

```
//made this non-template by removing template<T>
void InOrderThreadTree() {
    //implement
}

//made this non template
void InsertInOrderThreadTree() {
    //implement
    
}

//made this definition non template
void CreateBinaryTree() {
    //implement
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/znj6af51G)

---

Also [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)